# I created time using toLocaleString() and then I use this code to change the color every sec but it work only last color not for all

Tags: javascript

I create time using [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) and then I use this code to change the color every sec but it work only last color not for all.

```
var time=document.getElementById("time");

setInterval(function() {
  var da=new Date();
  var ti=da.toLocaleTimeString();
  // console.log("yes");
  time.innerHTML=ti;
}, 1000);

setInterval(function() {
  var arr=["red","blue","green"];
  var i=Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  // console.log(i);
  time.style.color=time.classList.add(arr[i]);
  console.log(i);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `time.style.color=time.classList.add(arr[i]);` is setting the `color` to `undefined`, you only need `time.classList.add(arr[i]);` or `time.style.color=arr[i];`, if you use the class approach, you need to make sure you remove the old class before adding the new class if you don't want them to clash

Comment: Your `var i` won't ever be set to `0`, so it will miss the colour `red`, you should be using `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`, or `Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)` if you want a random index from your array

Comment: I added an answer. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick to achieve the requirement you have.

To get the colors in sequence, try this **:**

```js
var time=document.getElementById("time");
var arr=["red","blue","green"];
let index = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  var da = new Date();
  var ti = da.toLocaleTimeString();
  time.innerHTML = ti;
  time.style.color = arr[index];
  if (index < arr.length) { index++; } else { index = 0 }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

To get the random color from an array, try this **:**

```js
var time=document.getElementById("time");
var arr=["red","blue","green"];

setInterval(function() {
  var da = new Date();
  var ti = da.toLocaleTimeString();
  time.innerHTML = ti;
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  time.style.color = arr[index];
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```